# Setting Airflow Environment Variables And Accessing Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are trying to create an Airflow Connection by setting an environment in Cloud Composer:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_GCP_CONN_ID=google_cloud_platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=<project_id>&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=<path_to_json_file>
```

In logs we are getting an warning complaining that credentials are not set.

> INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.

When we looked into internals of code we found that if `key_path` and `keyfile_data` are not set then we get this error. But we are setting `key_path` as mentioned in command.

For internal code we looked into [`gcp_api_base_hook.py`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py) on GitHub.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Composer? Have you tried setting the environmental variable using the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#adding_and_updating_environment_variables) command from cloud shell? `gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --location LOCATION \
  --update-env-variables=KEY=VALUE`

Comment: We are able to create environment variables but problem is Airflow code failing to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using cloud composer.
You can save your **service account credential file** into airflow environment. 
Goto **Admin -- Connection** `select google_cloud_default` and enter your service account details and the required **scope** you need to access.

Comment: Hi Ashish  i am trying to create environment  variables for connection. It is another way to use connections. Its working fine with airflow connection mechanism as you mentioned. But not working with another approach.

Comment: @SarangShinde is this are you talking about? https://github.com/airflow-plugins/variable_connection_plugin/blob/master/operator/variable_connection_operator.py